# as.POSIXct sometimes could not convert

Tags: format, standards, customstringconvertible

Please see the following example: some values could not be translated by `as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct("2019-03-21T07:51:41.521Z")

as.POSIXct("2019-03-22T05:35:47.824Z")
```

The first is working, however, the second one did not work what is the difference!

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in this part and not in some other part of your code? It does not look like the second string would be invalid.

Comment: I had a variable whose values are similar to these values, so "as.POSIXct" did not work for it. (on the other hand as.Date worked!!) I found that some of the values have a problem "one of them was the second value in my example" however I found no difference between the trouble maker values and other values! they seem completely similar!